# SQL Group By Order BY Descending on datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `services` table with the following column-rows on a MySQL database

```
`id`    `service_rendered`  `created_at`
 1       repair              2016-11-19 14:40:56
 2       install             2016-11-19 14:40:58
 3       repair              2016-11-19 14:44:27
 4       install             2016-11-19 14:50:35
```

I'm trying to count the number of services and the last date/time it was rendered. Column `created_at` is a datetime type.

The SQL statement that I'm running is:

```
SELECT COUNT(`service_rendered`) as `count_service`, `service_rendered`, `created_at` as `last_rendered`
FROM services
WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY `service_rendered`
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
`count_service`    `service_rendered`  `last_rendered`
 2                  repair              2016-11-19 14:40:56
 1                  install             2016-11-19 14:40:58
```

How do I write my SQL so that I am able to get 2016-11-19 14:44:27 on repair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) on the `created_at` column:

```
SELECT COUNT(`service_rendered`) AS `count_service`, `service_rendered`, MAX(`created_at`) AS `last_rendered`
FROM services
WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY `service_rendered`
ORDER BY `last_rendered` DESC
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3906b7/2

**You want to `ORDER BY created_at DESC`?**

You have to use the alias of the column `last_rendered`, so replace `ORDER BY created DESC` with `ORDER BY last_rendered DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the `max(created_date)` instead of `created_date` for `last_rendered`.
Then your query will become

```
select 
    count(service_rendered) as count_service,
    service_rendered,
    max(created_at) as last_rendered
from
    services
group by service_rendered
order by created_at desc
```

Comment: You missed `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`  what OP have added.